# Getting session variable in view contextual filter drupal 8

Tags: group

I am new to Drupal 8. I get group_id in session variable just like that `$_SESSION['groupbysession']['group_id'] = $path[2];`. now i want to get that session variable in view **Contextual filters**.I have no idea how to do this. I also use view extra module for this but doesn't work for me.Thanks in advance

Comment: `now i want to get that session variable in view Contextual filters` you mean you want to pass that session variable value as a contextual filter value?

Comment: Yes i want to pass that session variable value as a contextual filter value. Thanks for your reply

Comment: `I also use view extra module for this but doesn't work for me.` it would seem more pertinent to report "what doesn't work" to that module issue queue so they can fix a bug if in fact that is what is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a custom module and pass the value Group ID value using [hook_views_pre_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_view/8.2.x)

Example:

```
/*
 * Implements hook_views_pre_view()
 */
function mymodule_views_pre_view(ViewExecutable $view, $display_id, array &$args) {
  // Modify contextual filters for my_special_view.
  if ($view->id() == 'my_special_view') { // target a specific view
    // if you want you could make it even more specific by adding ex: "&& $display_id == 'block_1')"
    $group_id = $_SESSION['groupbysession']['group_id'];
    $args[0] = $group_id; // set argument
  }
}
```

Comment: @Kevin Thanks a lot for your response. I try it now.